# Common Utility for Exception Searching

Tags: java, exception

I wrote this little helper method to search the exception chain for a particular exception (either equals or super class).  However, this seems like a solution to a common problem, so was thinking it must already exist somewhere, possibly in a library I have already imported.  So, any ideas on if/where this might exist?

```
boolean exceptionSearch(Exception base, Class<?> search) {

    Throwable e = base;

    do {
        if (search.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())) {
            return true;
        }
    } while ((e = e.getCause()) != null);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey Andrew! 6 questions and none accepted? Did you know that you could accept answers by clicking on tick before answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into Google Guava project. They have quite a few handy classes including one for exceptions. Eg, functionality you've just requested could be implemented in the next way:

```
    boolean exceptionSearch(Exception base, Class<?> search) {
        return Throwables.getCausalChain(base).contains(search);
    }
```

Source code for this class: [Throwables](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/Throwables.java?r=28)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any utility to help solve this issue.  It does make me curious why you would want to do this.  There might be a better solution for your root objective.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Apache commons-lang ExceptionUtils.indexOfType does this:

public static int indexOfType(java.lang.Throwable throwable,
                              java.lang.Class type)